# Under what conditions does $P(A|B)=P(A|C) P(C|B)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose we have three Bernoulli random variables, $A$, $B$, and $C$. Under what conditions does $P(A|B)=P(A|C) P(C|B)$?

Comment: Well, what have you worked out thus far? Is there anything in particular that's causing you trouble in working this out?